# Об избыточности русского письма (по мотивам сочинений Галактион)

Tags: русская-графика, письменность

Это достаточно сложный и интересный вопрос - можно ли изъять из русского письма ту или иную букву. Очень жаль, что [[@Галактион](/users/996/%D0%B3%D0%B0%D0%BB%D0%B0%D0%BA%D1%82%D0%B8%D0%BE%D0%BD)](/users/996/%D0%B3%D0%B0%D0%BB%D0%B0%D0%BA%D1%82%D0%B8%D0%BE%D0%BD) многочисленными повторами этот вопрос зафлудил.

Проделайте такой опыт: вырежьте в плотном листе бумаги ма-аленьку дырочку; положите этот лист на газету и двигайте так, чтобы в дырочку попадало последовательно по одной букве; при каждом передвижении пытайтесь предсказать, какова будет следующая буква.

**Как вы думаете, какой процент букв вы сумеете предсказать правильно?** (этот процент и будет числовым выражением избыточности русских письменных текстов - в нашем случае газетных)

И второй вопрос: **Что будет, если уменьшить эту избыточность?** (не обязательно именно так, как предлагал Галактион) **Как уменьшение избыточности повлияет на процессы письма и чтения?**

upd 2013-09-27 =========== (удалён офф-топ)

Comment: 1. Жду ответов. Прочту с интересом.

2. Я не сомневаюсь, что: 1) писать "офицер" разумнее, чем писать "оффицер", 2) писать "илюзия" разумнее, чем писать "иллюзия", 3) писать "Талин" разумнее, чем писать "Таллинн", 4) писать "Вена" разумнее через "е".

Comment: Галактион, а "баллюстрада" что - неужели тоже с одним "л" писать?..

Comment: Если ограждение состоит из ба**лл**ясин, соединённых сверху пе**рр**илами и/или горизонтальной ба**лл**кой, тогда такое ограждение следует именовать ба**лл**юстрадой.

Comment: Наверное, по ба**лл**юстрадам ползают мо**лл**юски))) и набирают ба**лл**ы))) Да, резиденты камеди-клабов подыхают на нашем ресурсе...

Comment: @Галактион, маладэс! Я вас недооценил.

Comment: @stopkran. Ну, я не отрицаю, что я дилетант. И приведенная фраза мне самой не очень нравится, просто не было времени точнее выразить мысль. Приношу свои извинения.  
Написала комменты к вашему ответу. Изыдиваю. (?) Или как сказать "Изыди" в первом лице настоящем времени?

Comment: *Философическое*. Сложные вопросы трудно выносить на обсуждение. Каждый видит в них что-то свое, на это и отвечает. У меня был такой [опыт](http://russ.hashcode.ru/questions/7892/%D0%B3%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%BC%D0%BE%D1%82%D0%BD%D0%B0%D1%8F-%D1%80%D0%B5%D1%87%D1%8C-%D1%8F%D0%B2%D0%BB%D1%8F%D0%B5%D1%82%D1%81%D1%8F-%D0%BB%D0%B8-%D0%B3%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%BC%D0%BE%D1%82%D0%BD%D0%BE%D1%81%D1%82%D1%8C-%D1%84%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%BC%D0%BE%D0%B9-%D1%81%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%B1%D0%B8%D0%B7%D0%BC%D0%B0). Все свелось в охам "как понизилась грамотность" или предложениям убрать все лишние правила. А ведь речь была не об этом...

Comment: \- "исхожу", видимо. Сложность в другом, как мне кажется. Каждый из нас, задавая вопрос, неосознанно рассчитывает на отдачу - хочет получить немного внимания и усилий со стороны других участников. А "другие участники" хотят усилия сэкономить (тоже вряд ли осознанно).

Comment: Комментарии стремительно кончаются, а интерес - нет. Может, замутите на эту тему Исследование? Я бы у вас поработала доктором Ватсоном. Или, хотите - Санчо Пансой.

Comment: Пока нет. Я не понимаю, чем _исследование_ лучше. Можно ведь прямо здесь и сейчас писать новые ответы. Если есть ограничение на ответы, можно создать и новый вопрос.

Answer (score 3):

Нашёл в интернете забавный текст. Приводить его полностью не буду, так как есть нецензурная лексика, но принцип отмены лишних букв поясню. От графического вида буквы, по мнению автора нужно убрать лишние значки, например "Б" - это тот же "Ь", только с чёрточкой. Таким образом автор последовательно меняет:**Ё** на **Е**, **Й** на **И**, **Щ** на **Ш**, **Л** на **П**, **Ы, Б, В** на **Ь**, **Ю** на **О**, **Н** на **Ч** и довершает заменой **П=Л** на **Г**. Завершается текст следующим выводом:

> Итого! Мь изьаьпяемся от 10 ьукь грактически ьез готерь! Это гросто эьогоция язька, мь ж че догьоеьь чтоьь ьогочь атаьизмь? А скогько дечег смогут сэкочомить на тигографиях? А часкогько ььстрее и удоьчее стачет чаьирать ча кгаьиатуре — кгаьишь агфаьита стачет ча треть мечьше. Мб тьорим грогресс, и час че остачоьить этим чесчастчьм тормозам-огд-фагам. За чами ьудушее! И че смотрите, что читается трудчо — это ьсего-гишь дего гриььчки.

Данный текст, хоть и не без труда но прочитать можно, наш мозг готов приспособиться к чему угодно. Вопрос только в том,  а нужно ли?

Comment: пять баллов!

Comment: Ну, опять флуд начинается. Сам по себе пример очень уместен. Но вопрос-то был - "каковы последствия?", а не "зачем?". 

Ясно, что вот именно так, как в примере, делать - "незачем", но вот букву Ъ изъять или букву Ё ведь достаточно серьёзно многие предлагают.

И я привёл в вопросе алгоритм "предельного" случая, когда из русского письма можно будет изъять вообще **все** лишние буквы. Напоминаю вопрос: **как это отразится на пишущем и на читающем?**

Comment: Это не флуд. Это целенаправленная деятельность "историка, интересующегося русским языком". Мол, Пётр I менял "шило" на "мыло", когда потребовал изъять 10 букв из русского алфавита и ввести повсеместно гражданский шрифт.

Comment: @stopkran, в том и дело, что если поменять одну условность на другую, то по большому счету ничего не изменится. Даже утрированный текст из моего ответа вполне читаем, что уж говорить о менее радикальных вариантах реформы.

Реформа 1918 была вызвана необходимостью убрать буквы во всех позициях обозначающие одинаковые звуки, те же преследовала и реформа Петра I. Без "Ъ" обойтись можно, но его всё равно придётся заменять на другой знак, так как *съел* и *сел* - это разные слова.

Comment: @Марк Из, вы можете ответить на вопрос "как **это** отразится на процессах письма и чтения?" - подставив под "это" любой из упомянутых вариантов (Л на П и др. из вашего примера || Ъ || полное удаление избыточности...)?

Comment: @stopkran, Первое время будет непривычно и волна неприятия, потом грамотные привыкнут, далее появится поколение,  для которых диковинным станет старое написание и в конце концов о старом письме забудут.

Последствия реформ подобного плана можно увидеть воочию на примере недавней реформы немецкого письма (материал о ней есть и в рунете).

Answer (score 3):

Я не знаю точного ответа на свои вопросы. Кое-что знаю, кое-что предполагаю, кое-что хотел бы уточнить. Здесь не совсем ответ, а больше накапливание материала. Да, и ещё: речь не идёт о реформе орфографии (отстаньте уже в этом от меня! :-) и абстрагируйтесь от Галактиона - он лишь дал мне повод), я в принципе против любых реформ (против даже очевидного "парашУта").

Начну с упомянутого Марк Изом двоичного кодирования. В компьютере текстовый файл может занимать, например, 30 килобайт. А если его упаковать архиватором, получится 15 килобайт. Вот при этой упаковке как раз и происходит ликвидация избыточности. Но только той, которую можно формализовать для компьютера (без учёта семантики).

Далее, мы можем наблюдать факт "сжатия", например, в текстах БСЭ (с целым набором сокращений для большого количества слов).

Вот текст, в котором при последовательном чтении по одной букве я удалил угаданные мной буквы (то есть удалил избыточность, существующую для меня за счёт знаний грамматики и семантики):

> (Статья после выборов в Законодательное собрание) Людмила Б. умна, хитра и осторожна. Внимательные зрите__ за______, ч__ во вс_м предв_______ проц____ она ни р___, что на________, н_ "засв_______". Прек_____ по_____, ч__ вы____ в абсо____ых ци____ бу___ неут_________ми, спи___ За_с_______ первого со____ аккур____ устр____ась о_ пуб__чных выст_______, прог___ов и обе_____...

Глядя на этот текст, можно легко сделать несколько упрощённых выводов:

1. Такой текст прочитать можно.
2. Такой текст читать сложно (дольше, чем обычный).
3. Такой текст (что уже менее очевидно :-) *писать* сложно (дольше, чем обычный).

В пределе мы можем создать систему записи с использованием всех возможных (и формальных, и семантических) алгоритмов "удаления лишнего". Но тогда писать и читать будет не просто "труднее" (типа все плеваться будут) - большинство людей станут *полностью* "безграмотными", они вообще не смогут общаться на таком "языке". Иначе все давно бы пользовались только стенографией.

Следствие из Упрощённого вывода 2: избыточность *повышает скорость обмена информацией* при общении людей. Для компьютеров это не всегда так: иногда быстрее скачать упакованный файл и распаковать его, чем скачать сразу незаархивированный файл (это зависит от файлов).

Применяем Следствие к материалу "Галактионовых сочинений": Ъ, Ё, ЯТЬ, сложные случаи написания - всё это **повышает** скорость чтения, *облегчает*, а не затрудняет восприятие текстов.

Что касается пишущего, то здесь, как справедливо заметила [[[[@DocentI](/users/508/docenti)](/users/508/docenti)](/users/508/docenti)](/users/508/docenti), избыточность бывает разная: например, простая добавка Ъ в конце слов не очень замедлит процесс письма, а вот сложные орфограммы могут серьёзно снижать (и снижают!) скорость написания текстов.

upd 2013-09-28 ==============

[[[[@DocentI](/users/508/docenti)](/users/508/docenti)](/users/508/docenti)](/users/508/docenti), думаю, что всё-таки избыточность формируется из всего: "текста" (сочетаемости букв), грамматики (предсказуемых окончаний), и смысла тоже. Я прочитал перед описанным в ответе опытом пол-статьи о тех же выборах, поэтому сумел предсказать, например, слово "Заксобрание". А вы, не обладая той же "предварительной" информацией, не смогли это слово расшифровать.

==========

[[@Яzz](/users/1864/%D1%8Fzz)](/users/1864/%D1%8Fzz), **урок** литературы в таком сокращении невозможен. Ваша "стенография" (и наше её понимание) стала возможной именно благодаря тому, что у вас (и у всех нас) когда-то был *полный*, развёрнутый урок на эту тему, а потом вы ещё раз 50 читали о таких уроках.

Для каждого русского образованного человека ваша сокращённая запись является аллюзией, "культурной ссылкой". Благодаря аллюзиям поэт может сделать текст очень насыщенным, содержащим в каждой строчке (ну, почти в каждой) отсылки к известным современникам культурным фактам, реалиям. Да вы поэт! :-)

Comment: Ответ интересный, хотя приведенный текст я не осилила. Думаю, мое первое неприятие вопроса и нежелание его серьезно обсуждать было отчасти связано со ссылкой на Галактиона.  
Некоторые соображения. Такое **радикальное** уменьшение избыточности дает плохой результат. Но это не значит, что в современном письменном языке все правила логичны и удобны. И вполне возможно, что можно упорядочить язык наилучшим образом для целей восприятия. Только  
1) его сложно разработать  
2) его надо будет долго "внедрять"  
2) живой язык "подкинет" новые непонятки

Comment: Впрочем, усиление роли компьютеров в автоматической обработке текстов, возможно, станет аргументом (и средством) к тому, чтобы такую работу все-таки начать.

Comment: @Docent, представил  урок литературы без "избыточности":

А. С. "Я В..." - остальное избыточно. :)

Comment: Нет, в современном русском письме ПОЛНО неудобных, плохих правил. Но их не надо менять. Слово - это _знак_. А знак должен быть неизменным. Если "парашют" мы начнём писать через "у", знак изменится. Изменение знака - это для языка, как... ну, всё равно что Пушкина в гробу перевернуть.

Comment: Dear stopkran.

Пожалуйста, продолжайте.

Comment: @Яzz, избыточность текста и избыточность смысла не коррелируют. Возьмите Цветаеву: вот уж кто боролся с избыточностью, побольше самого @Галактион-а.  
>"Жить так, как пишу, образцово и сжато, как бог повелел и друзья не велят".

Comment: @Галактион, я не очень уловил суть вашего (уже закрытого) вопроса, где вы цитируете мой абзац про гроб Пушкина. На всякий случай: в этом абзаце была метафора. Или гипербола. Неважно, потому что сути это не меняет: знак в системе должен быть постоянным; изменение одного знака меняет всю систему, и это для системы плохо.

Если честно, я ожидал тут от вас следующего ясного и простого (детского) вопроса: если постоянство знака так важно для языка, откуда же тогда берутся новые слова и значения? (задай вы такой вопрос без этих ваших "невозражений" - и к вам бы очередь отвечающих выстроилась...)

Comment: Dear stopkran.
Пожалуйста, не расстраивайтесь из-за того, что Вы "не очень уловили суть" моего "(уже закрытого) вопроса".

Comment: Нет, я всё-таки расстраиваюсь. И потому провоцирую вас на создание правильных, годных вопросов.

Answer (score 2):

> Как уменьшение избыточности повлияет на процессы письма и чтения?

Переучиваться придется. И сколько же людей будут клясть "реформаторов"! Ох, будет им икаться, чувствую.

Comment: Я готов был принять примерно такой ответ от историка. Но не от математика. Неужели вам самой не интересно _измерить_ отклонения от статус-ква?

Когда мы говорим об одной букве - да, народ поплюётся и через два года привыкнет. А если убрать избыточность полностью (ничего лишнего в текстах - представляете?)?

Comment: @stopkran, азбука Морзе вполне обходится двумя знакам,  так что излишками можно считать любое количество знаков больше двух.

Comment: Марк Из, ну вот вопрос же был математику! :-) Азбука Морзе нисколько не уменьшает избыточность письма.

Comment: Именно как математик я с большой осторожностью отношусь к применению количественных методов в неподходящих задачах. Для простого статистического вывода нужно штук 30 экспериментов в **практически идентичных условиях**. Где вы столько наберете?

Comment: @DocentI, _мне_ не надо набирать "столько", я и так знаю, что избыточность русских газетных текстов - 70% *. Метод измерения избыточности был предложен участникам, чтобы попробовать и убедиться самим - из чистого любопытства. 

=============================

\* Яглом А.М., Яглом И.М. Вероятность и информация. - 3-е изд., перераб. и доп. - М.: Наука, 1973. - 512с.

Comment: Да я не о том. Вы же начали с того, можно ли убрать буквы, а кончили вопрос тем, что будет, если *уменьшить* избыточность. Вот на этот вопрос математически не ответишь, надо взять с десяток стран, провести реформу и подождать с десяток лет.  
А изботочность в любом коде нужна для его надежности. Чтобы можно было восстановить смысл при наличии ошибок.

Comment: Кстати, в восточных сказках чтение часто изображается так: писец читает текст, обдумывает его и рассказывает калифу. Ну, что калиф сам немчитает, еще куда ни шло (не царское это дело). А вот зачем обдумывать? Я предполагаю, это - следствие отсутствия гласных на письме, из-за чего текст превращается в некую головоломку, которую писец и должен разгадать.  
Кстати, избыточность в 70% - локальная или глобальная? Сколько предыдущих букв надо знать, чтобы угадать следующую? Если эту избыточность убрать, смысл отдельных слов придется "извлекать" из всего контекста.

Comment: @DocentI, в каком месте моего начального вопроса _я задаю сообществу вопрос_ "Можно ли убрать буквы?"?

Все мои **вопросы** выделены в заглавном сообщении темы жирным шрифтом.

Локальная или глобальная, вам станет намного понятнее, если вы наконец возьмёте уже этот листок бумаги и проведёте опыт самостоятельно, не гадая по звёздам.

Если просто хотите готовый результат подсмотреть, возьмите цитируемую мной книгу.

И вот мы начинаем с хх-го захода подходить к сути (ура!): **смысл отдельных слов придётся извлекать из всего контекста**. А если подумать, то и не "отдельных"...

Comment: Если я правильно поняла последний коммент, Вы "знаете" ответ на свой вопрос, просто хотели, чтобы и мы подумали? Ну, тогда я удаляюсь, мне не интюересно.

Answer (score 2):

Орфография (в широком смысле, т.е. правописание вообще) - единственное в языке, что несет в себе огромную долю субъективности. Но не более чем долю. Разговоры об избыточности - миф, построенный на непонимании последнего факта. 
Даже отмена ятя и конечного ера не была отменой *абсолютно* избыточных графем. 
Короче, всякое предложение орфографических изменений должно решаться не не уровне кухонных посиделок, к чему призывает г-н Галактион, а содержать в себе хотя бы минимальный анализ причин и последствий. Здесь не имеем ни того, ни другого, кроме, разве, маловразумительных реплик, что так будет удобнее г-ну Галактиону.

Будет ли реально удобно всем остальным - вопрос весьма спорный. Но зато очевидно, что при этом будет поставлен под сомнение базовый принцип русской орфографии - фонетико-морфологический (его по-разному называют, не здесь о том спорить) - это "факт на лице".

И еще реплика в сторону. Зачем с такой упертостью что-то доказывать тем, кто все равно не уполномочен решать подобные вопросы?! Мнение давно было сформулировано довольно единодушно: Галактион фигней страдает и переубедить нас в этом невозможно. В данной теме имеем ту же галактионовщину, ну, может, немного другими словами сформулированную.

Comment: >и переубедить _нас_ в этом невозможно

Ну, не так уж всё однозначно плохо. Галактион обратил _наше_ внимание на некоторые интересные свойства русского языка. Галактион задал достаточно интересный "детский" вопрос ("почему нельзя изъять из русского письма пару-тройку буков?").

Мне этот вопрос интересен.

Comment: Поддерживаю, мне также интересен этот вопрос, ведь и бывшие в языке  орфографические реформы в своё время вызывали негодование пуристов-ревнителей, а сейчас мы готовы признать, что, скажем "ер" и впрямь был избыточным знаком, его изъятие последствий не возымело. Вопрос: а есть ли сейчас в языке такие знаки, которые можно устранить без последствий? Поиск ответа на этот вопрос (даже в чисто теоретическом ключе, причём тут то, что мы не уполномочены решать этот вопрос на должном уровне?) мне интересен.

Comment: Простите, а что общего имеют потуги г. Галактиона с реальными проблемами, связанными с реформой орфографии?  
  
Я готов подключится к обсуждению, если автор предложения начнет с внятного вопроса на ответ "А зачем?" А вопрос "что будет" и "чему противоречит" - это логика пятилетки, дорвавшегося до маминой швейной машинки.

Comment: ну, так я же и говорю - "детский вопрос". И ещё говорю: мне он интересен. О чём тут можно спорить? :-)

И ответ на вопрос "а зачем?" для меня совершенно ясен: из чистого любопытства.

Answer (score 1):

Автор вопроса описал метод определения избыточности письма, который я не понимаю. Поэтому я позволю себе взглянуть на понятие "избыточность письма" так, как мне это удобно.

Сравним два текста:

1) "Иногда я провожу отпуск на Ч**ё**рном море. **В ч**астности, в этом году я отдыхал в Оде**сс**е.",

2) "Иногда я провожу отпуск на Ч**о**рном море. **Вч**астности, в этом году я отдыхал в Оде**с**е.".

Очевидно, что второй текст немного короче, чем первый. Вместе с тем, местные знатоки русского языка (как и весь советский народ - *прим.* Г.Т.) заклеймят автора второго текста как безграмотное существо, но сделают это только после того, как осознают, что смысл первого текста совпадает со смыслом второго текста.

Проанализируем ошибки "безграмотного существа" (БГ), начиная с конца текста.

БГ назвало город Одесса по-украински, а именно Одеса. *Видимо, БГ - недообрусевший украинец.* Но если бы такое БГ-шное правописание было принято в России, тогда бы страна Россия стала более привлекательной для "братьев наших меньших": журавлей и т. п.

БГ убрало пробел между словом "в" и словом "частности". *Видимо, БГ не знает, что вводное словосочетание "в частности" пишется раздельно, а вводное слово "например" пишется вместе.* Но если бы БГ-шное правописание было принято в России, тогда бы страна Россия стала более привлекательной для вышеуказанных "братьев".

БГ написало букву "о" вместо буквы "ё" в слове "чёрный". *Видимо, БГ не знает, что  советские филологи отвергли представления русских филологов начала 20 века.* Но если бы БГ-шное правописание было принято в России, тогда бы страна Россия стала более привлекательной для вышеуказанных "братьев".

Руководствуясь изложенным, можно найти всех выгодоприобретателей от БГ-шного правописания.

Comment: Предложенный мной (точнее, Б.Ягломом) метод определения избыточности не надо "понимать", его надо _просто_ использовать. Если у вас две руки, я думаю, вы сможете вырезать в плотной бумаге маленькую дырочку. Ну, или попросите помочь товарищей.

Comment: Я не умею использовать то, чего не понимаю.

Comment: Ну, давайте я окажу вам техподдержку. Что именно у вас не получается? Дырочку вырезать смогли? Газета под рукой есть (любая книга, журнал, брошюра, парашют...)? Получилось положить листок на газету так, чтобы в дырочке была видна одна буква (можно и две-три)?

=======================

Теперь возьмите другой чистый листок бумаги - на нём будем записывать результаты.

=======================

Итак, вы видите одну газетную букву - например, "К". Можете угадать, какая будет в строке следующая? если нет, запишите на чистый листок знак 0.

Двигайте листок с дыркой дальше. Видите, допустим, букву "т

Comment: Можете угадать, какая следующая? - правильно, "о". Запишите в чистый листок знак 1 (в отдельной строке). Угадываем следующую - "пробел" - запишем 1. Следующую не знаем - 0. Оказалось, что она - "в". Угадываем целое слово - следующие 6 буков - записываем 6 единиц.

===================

Итого, из 10 символов (с пробелом) мы угадали 8. Избыточность газетного заголовка "Кто виноват?" - 80%. Это непоказательно, для надёжного результата нам надо пройти хотя бы букв 500 (ну, или сколько хватит терпения).

Comment: Dear stopkran.

Предлагаю Вам удалить Ваш комментарий, чтобы "не кормить тролля" (цит. по behemothus'у).

P.S. Если желаете, сообщите о Ваших успехах по сбору подписей в защиту дефиса.

Comment: > чтобы "не кормить тролля" 

Ну, виноват, ошибся. Подумал, может, вам правда интересно. А удалять свои комментарии - это дурновкусие и грумантщина.

Answer (score 1):

Есть известный эксперимент, суть которого заключается в том, что убираются из текста все гласные буквы. При этом русскоязычный текст остается понятным. Секрет в том, что мы слова воспринимаем целиком. И более того - нужные слова мы подставляем из контекста.

Небольшое мини-исследование по теме можно найти на ресурсе [Хабрахабр](http://habrahabr.ru/post/148896/). В этом исследовании проверено сохраняется ли узнаваемость текста при различных перестановках букв и при удалении какой-либо определенной категории букв.

Answer (score 0):

Зависит от стиля речи. В официально-деловом стиле, подобным способом можно предугадать наверно, процентов до 90 информации. В непринуждённой разговорной речи (молодёжные чаты) вряд ли больше 10. Только если делопроизводство начнут вести на молодёжном сленге, избыточность словесная изменится в избыточность мыслительную, необходимую для расшифровки каждого предложения исходя из всего текста.